# Crash while adding google account

Tags: google-account

Facing trouble while adding Google account to my android device. In logcat I got these two messages:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmService:
  java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10073 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES. 
  java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10073 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
```

Screen shot of my device Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.2.2)

[image: This is the Screen shot of my device Samsung Galaxy s3 (4.2.2)] [image: while restarting]
<sup>Screen shot of my device Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.2.2) / while restarting</sup>

Comment: Did you just install an update to your device? Or did you do a factory-reset? The second screenshot indicates the Dalvik cache being updated, which points to one of these two possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall CM with minimal gapps, your /system folder is most probably full due to gapps-kk taking up too much space.

http://goo.im/devs/BaNkS/GApps/4.4.3

Comment: what is CM and how can i   minimal gapps?

Comment: CM stands for "CyanogenMod" and is a custom ROM. So this answer is unlikely to apply to your issue if you didn't install a custom ROM.

Comment: If you're not running CM/CyanogenMod/Custom rom, do please "root" your phone, and check if there's enough space on the /system partition. If that's not the cause - i'd suggest cleaning up app data for google play services & later doing a factory reset if cleaning up the app data didn't help (but fist back up your data).